# Is there a specific Sandhyavandanam for Vaishya varna i.e different from what is usually prescribed for Brahmins?

Tags: vedas, varna, sandhyavandanam, vaishya

Brahmins usually have Sandhyavandanam rituals as per the Veda associated with their family. For example, Yajurveda (there are some sub-branches as well) or Samveda. Is there a Sandhyavandanam ritual for Vaishya varna that does NOT have the strict association with birth i.e. anyone can learn and religiously practise as part of and to aid in their profession as a businessman.